# Если введено 10 символов в поле поиска, запустить серверный php

Tags: jquery, javascript

Доработка `Select2`
Как, сохранив функции поиска, добавить условие: 
если введено 10 символов в поле поиска, запустить серверный php?

Comment: @eicto велосипед на велосипеде :)

У плагина есть такой параметр, как:

      minimumInputLength

Comment: @lampa не заметил :) но все равно initSelection надо делать. хотя там ещё опция ajax есть...

Comment: На велосипеде я :)
Если я правильно понимаю minimumInputLength - минимальная длина вводимых знаков после которых начинается поиск. 

Мне нужно, чтобы Select2 обрабатывал  minimumInputLength=3, а при событии 10 OnKeyPress передать серверному скрипту содержимое нажатого.

Comment: а до этого где он будет брать данные ?

Comment: если вы ещё 50 раз напишите одно и то-же ничего не изменится в плане понимания того что вы пытаетесь сделать. сценарий работы с этим полем со стороны юзера как будет выглядеть ? (и еще - что за текстовый файл ?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Смотрите сюда: http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/

Раздел: **Loading Remote Data**